# Как адаптировать сайт под разные устройства с помощью CSS?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, media-queries

Нужно, чтобы сайт на телефоне смотрелся также как и на компьютере. Команда `@media` мне чего-то не помогает или я её не правильно применяю.

Comment: а в чем помочь, то...код в студию! ps нужно использовать `@media` запросы

Comment: `@media screen and (max-width: npx) {
  'нужный блок' {
    меняем
  }

}`

Answer (score 1):

Команда @media - правильно употребленная, конечно - позволяет Вам использовать нужные стили для каждого разрешения экрана - от и до, как правило.

Если вы этих стилей не задали (что делается при отработке желательного отображения/вида при том или ином разрешении), то не viewport, ни медиа-запросы не помогут - они являются триггерами включения стилей при определенных условиях.

Как правило, есть общее стилевое оформление определенных элементов, общих для всех разрешений, и спецификация нужных по медиа-запросам.

Сайт нужно переделывать вручную в адаптив, согласно желаемому видению, либо переводить на какой-либо css-фреймворк - bootstrap и т.д.